# Internet via ethernet, switch and another pc wifi

Tags: linux, windows, networking, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have two pc. One has Internet via WiFi and the other one has not the WiFi board, only ethernet.

If I install a dhcp server in the one with the WiFi and then connect both to a switch, would I be able to use Internet with the one that has the lan only?

The one with WiFi ha Windows, the other Linux.

Can the firewall be a problem right?

Comment: Windows has a native internet sharing feature, sort of a "bridge" between two network devices. No switch need, a cross pair LAN cable is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So do I need 5o activate something? The other pc uses Linux, it feels strange that it will work out of the box without dhcp

Comment: The internet sharing feature takes care of that.

Comment: That's really cool, I hope it works also with a switch as now I have just standard cables. Thank you again

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Couldn't find a good duplicate so I did as you suggested.

Comment: You can use “standard” or “straight through” cables. All modern networking equipment detects and adjusts for the type of capable you plug in. No cross over cable is needed.

Answer (score 1):

No switch is required (but can be used).

Windows has native ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) that should do exactly what you're looking for.

According to [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/internet-connection-sharing-in-windows-10/f6dcac4b-5203-4c98-8cf2-dcac86d98fb9) for Windows 10, here are the steps:

> 

1. Press **Windows key + X** to open the **Power User** menu and select **Network Connections**.
2. Right-click the network adapter with an Internet connection (Ethernet or wireless network adapter), then select **Properties**.
3. Click **Sharing**.
4. Put a check mark on **Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection**.
5. From the **Home networking connection** drop-down menu, select the **Microsoft Hosted Virtual Adapter**.
6. Click **OK** to finish.

Now all it needs is a cross pair Ethernet cable if connected directly. If connected via a network switch it shouldn't matter.

No additional DHCP server required.